# Is it possible to use placeholders in JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, pdo

I have this following SQL query which is used to output forum posts with posts' relevant data in relational tables (user that posted it, forum/thread that it's a child of etc).

I am using PDO positional placeholders (hence the ?'s)

```
SELECT {Lots of select stuff here}
FROM tab_posts tposts
INNER JOIN tab_users tuser ON tuser.id=?
INNER JOIN tab_users tusers ON tposts.user_id=tusers.id
INNER JOIN tab_ranks tranks ON tusers.rank_id=tranks.id
INNER JOIN tab_avatars tavatars ON tusers.avatar_id=tavatars.id
INNER JOIN tab_threads tthreads ON tposts.thread_id=tthreads.id
INNER JOIN tab_forums tforums ON tthreads.forum_id=tforums.id
WHERE tposts.thread_id=? AND tforums.rank_id <= tuser.rank_id
```

So in this query I'm using 2 placeholders, first one is the ID of the user retrieved from session, the other is the thread id retrieved from the request (to ensure we're only listing posts that belong to that thread).

`tuser` is the session user, `tusers` is the alias for the user that submitted the post. I'm only requiring `tuser` to check whether the session user is allowed to view those posts (by access rank, the `rank_id` in the forums table is the minimum allowed rank).

I would just like to confirm whether using a placeholder in the JOIN section (or rather, a variable at all) is valid? Or am I limited to using tables? I'm pretty sure I'm using it incorrectly, in which case how else could I be checking for the user's rank?

I'm also not sure if my other JOIN's are valid actually, bah ! (I'm new to using JOIN if you couldn't tell)

Comment: Why not just add `tuser.id = ?` to your WHERE component? Then you can avoid the more taxing INNER JOIN.

Comment: Placeholders are used for anything that represents a **value**. In other words, yes, you can use it like you did because you're passing on two integers. You can't use it for table names or for column names though. When you think about it, the thing that a placeholder represents is either a number or a quoted string after everything's done and ready to be executed.

Comment: Joins are for SELECTing columns from other tables, not limiting the result of your query. If you are trying to limit the result of your query to a smaller subset then it belongs in the where clause. If you need to check another table for a value that you are not selecting from, then use a sub-query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use placeholders in a `JOIN`'s `ON` clause when it is appropriate to do so.  The `ON` condition just has to be some expression which evaluates to `TRUE` when compared row to row between two tables, so a condition like

```
FROM
  t1
  LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.othercol = ?
```

would be a valid use of the `?` placeholder in the `ON`. In a joining condition like the one above, both the match on `id` columns *and* the `othercol` column matching the `?` input value must be true for the join to be met. You'll see this usage commonly in `LEFT JOIN`s when more than just a column match is required to relate the tables, but adding a `WHERE` condition would incorrectly cause the `LEFT JOIN` to omit `NULL`s and therefore behave like an `INNER JOIN`.

In your case however, it looks like you really just need to move that user condition into the `WHERE` clause to filter the result set to the requested user id.

```
SELECT {Lots of select stuff here}
FROM tab_posts tposts
  INNER JOIN tab_users tusers ON tposts.user_id = tusers.id
  INNER JOIN tab_ranks tranks ON tusers.rank_id = tranks.id
  INNER JOIN tab_avatars tavatars ON tusers.avatar_id = tavatars.id
  INNER JOIN tab_threads tthreads ON tposts.thread_id = tthreads.id
  INNER JOIN tab_forums tforums ON tthreads.forum_id = tforums.id
WHERE 
  /* This condition belongs in the WHERE */
  tusers.id = ?
  tposts.thread_id = ?
  AND tforums.rank_id <= tuser.rank_id
```

Your remaining joins look correct, as long as your tables are actually laid out the way the joins express them.

To generalize this just a little more, `?` placeholders may be used anywhere that you would otherwise use a scalar value in your query; that is, a string or numeric value (or boolean, blob, etc). So you can use them as function arguments for example:

```
/* Truncate a column to some ? number of characters */
SELECT LEFT(column, ?)
```

Or a scalar value in the `SELECT` list:

```
/* Add an additional string suffix to every row in a column */
SELECT CONCAT(column, ?)
```

You *cannot* use a `?` in place of a table or column name, though. They only work for scalar values.

Comment: I feel stupid, not sure why using it in WHERE clause didn't occur to me lol. Well it's good to know that they can be used in join's if I ever need to, thanks for the descriptive answer.

Comment: @Sakuya I added a bit more about `?` use cases to generalize this beyond joins.